# Display a custom themed "my-account.php" woocommerce page based on user role

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

We've been building out a new digital dashboard for my client's upcoming launch of a new digital product, however we wish to only provide access to this newly skinned and structured WooCommerce dashboard (my-account template pages) IF the user has been manually provided a user-role, ie: beta_user, org_manager

Any users who do not have this custom role applied would be served the default WooCommerce plugin my-account pages.

Here is what we have tried...

**Added this snippet to the Child Theme functions.php:**

```
// allow access to new dashboard if user role is org manager 
function isOrgManager(){
    $currentUser = wp_get_current_user();
    return in_array('org_manager', $currentUser->roles);
}
```

**Then applied this to the /child-theme/woocommerce/my-account.php file:**

```
<?php if( isOrgManager() ){
        wc_get_template( '/wp-content/themes/blankchildhub/woocommerce/my-account.php' ); 
    } else {        
    wc_get_template( 'myaccount/my-account.php' );
}?>
```

Any insight would be greatly appreciated as I know this is a fairly common challenge for custom WP and WooCommerce managers.

Comment: Using `wc_get_template( 'myaccount/my-account.php' );` in the _"my-account.php"_ template file is useless, as the file would call itself. Just modify the template file itself where you put the current code in an else condition, in the if condition you can then run your new desired content

Answer (score -1, accepted):

First remove the old file `/child-theme/woocommerce/my-account.php`

and then copy `/plugins/woocommerce/templates/my-account/my-account.php`

to `/child-theme/woocommerce/my-account.php`

then add a switch/ if statement something like below:

```
<?php

/*** filename /child-theme/woocommerce/my-account.php ***/

/**
 * My Account page
 *
 * This template can be overridden by copying it to yourtheme/woocommerce/myaccount/my-account.php.
 *
 * HOWEVER, on occasion WooCommerce will need to update template files and you
 * (the theme developer) will need to copy the new files to your theme to
 * maintain compatibility. We try to do this as little as possible, but it does
 * happen. When this occurs the version of the template file will be bumped and
 * the readme will list any important changes.
 *
 * @see     https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/template-structure/
 * @package WooCommerce\Templates
 * @version 3.5.0
 */

defined( 'ABSPATH' ) || exit;

/**
 * My Account navigation.
 *
 * @since 2.6.0
 */


// allow access to new dashboard if user role is org manager 
function isOrgManager(){
    $currentUser = wp_get_current_user();
    return in_array('org_manager', $currentUser->roles);
}

<?php

if( isOrgManager() ):

// your custom code....

else:      

do_action( 'woocommerce_account_navigation' ); ?>

<div class="woocommerce-MyAccount-content">
    <?php
        /**
         * My Account content.
         *
         * @since 2.6.0
         */
        do_action( 'woocommerce_account_content' );
    ?>
</div>

<?php

  endif;
```

Comment: Hi Json - thanks for taking a look at this! I've modified my OP with updated notes from your response. Thank you!